# How to set a variable to the variable inside a variable in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, posix

I need to write a POSIX shell script that will change system configurations. Before doing so I want to ensure there are backups of any file I edit.
A requirement for this script is that is uses `dmenu` to prompt the user if installed and `read` if not.
I want one function (named `communicate` below) that will automatically handle this for me based on a variable that gets set on run, *$dmenu*.

I'm having issues writing to a variable inside a variable, as shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

[ $(command -v dmenu 2>/dev/null) ] && dmenu='true'

communicate(){
    description="$1"; options="$2"; outcome="$3"
    if [ $dmenu ]; then
        echo "$(printf "$options" | dmenu -i -p "$description")" >&0 | read $outcome
    else
        printf "$description $options "; read $outcome
    fi
}

backup(){
    [ $1 ] && file="$1" || communicate 'Enter file: ' '' 'file'
    [ ! -f $file ] && backup "$1"
    cp "$file" "$file.bak"
}

select_interface(){
    [ $1 ] && interface="$1" || communicate 'Select interface:' "$interfaces" 'interface'
}
```

`backup` wants to save user input to a variable called *$file*, whereas later `select_interface` wants to save to a variable called *$interface*.
if `dmenu` is not installed, writing to $outcome works fine with the else statement, whereas if it is installed, I cannot seem to get the `read` command to trigger when passing the outcome of `dmenu` through with the STDIN redirect into read, which works outside of the script.

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong or how I could do this better?
I need it all to be in the one function *communicate*, acting as the communicating agent with the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

```
echo "$(printf "$options" | dmenu -i -p "$description")" >&0 | read $outcome
```

being a pipe, causes the shell to implement `echo` and `read` as 2 separate processes. `read` is still a forked shell, and it still sets the variable `$outcome`, but it only sets it in the forked shell, not in the forking (parent) shell.

The technically correct way to do it is:

```
eval $outcome=\$\(printf "$options" \| dmenu -i -p "$description"\)'
```

**BUT** I would advise against eval for anything but throwaway code.

I also advise against functions which accept variable names to set, it's pretty hard to get right.

The cleaner way to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

if [ $(command -v dmenu 2>/dev/null) ]; then
    communicate() {
        description="$1"
        options="$2"
        # also fixed this bug with the menu selection, each option needs to be in a new line
        printf "%s\n" $options | dmenu -i -p "${description}:"
    }
else
    communicate() {
        description="$1"
        options="$2"
        if [ -n "$options" ]; then
            optstring="options: ${options}; "
        else
            optstring=""
        fi
        read -p "${optstring}${description}: " outcome
        echo $outcome
    }
fi

backup() {
    if [ -n "$1" ]; then
        file="$1"
    else
        file=$(communicate 'Enter file')
    fi
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        cp "$file" "${file}.bak"
    else
        backup
    fi
}

select_interface() {
    if [ -n "$1" ]; then
        interface="$1"
    else
        interface=$(communicate "Enter interface" "$interfaces")
    fi
}
```